# How to encode to character U+FFFD in Flutter?

Tags: kotlin, flutter

I do encrypt with SHA-512 from `String` in Flutter.

The result is in hex code but I want to return like Kotlin.

Kotlin:

```
val text = "1234567890";
val charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8
val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512")
val digest = md.digest(text.toByteArray(charset))
val result = digest.toString(charset)
```

Flutter:

```dart
var text = "1234567890";
var bytes1 = utf8.encode(text);
var digest1 = sha512.convert(bytes1);
var result = digest1.toString();
```

Flutter: 12b03226a6d8be9c6e8cd5e55dc6c7920caaa39df14aab92d5e3ea9340d1c8a4d3d0b8e4314f1f6ef131ba4bf1ceb9186ab87c801af0d5c95b1befb8cedae2b9

Kotlin: �2&�ؾ�n���]�ǒ ����J�����@�Ȥ�и�1O n�1�K�ι j�|� ���[ ����

Comment: What does "encode to character U+FEFF" and "encode to character U+FFFD" mean?  It's not clear what problem you're having.  Also [`Sha512.convert`](https://pub.dev/documentation/crypto/latest/crypto/Hash/convert.html) returns a `Digest`, from which you either can get a list of [bytes](https://pub.dev/documentation/crypto/latest/crypto/Digest/bytes.html) *or* a [`String` of hexadecimal digits](https://pub.dev/documentation/crypto/latest/crypto/Digest/toString.html).

Comment: So does using `digest1.bytes` instead of `digest1.toString()` do what you want?

Comment: bytes is not what i need

Comment: I want something like kotlin output but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you clarify *why* you want the Kotlin output?  I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but it seems like you're taking an arbitrary stream of bytes and trying to interpret it as UTF-8, which is a wrong thing to do.

Comment: And if that's *really* what you want (which is highly questionable), then you could call [`utf8.decode(digest1.bytes, allowMalformed: true)`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-convert/Utf8Codec/decode.html).

Comment: oh it's work now thank you @jamesdlin